# octomap_server problems

Tags: rviz, octomap, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I simulate a robot in gazebo while it maps the environment using octomap_server. I have 2 questions regarding the visualization.

1. the mapped octomap cells get cleared after some time if the robot does not re-visit the area previously mapped. Why is this happenning?
2. why the colors of the octomap changing after a while?

Thank you

CS

##########
Edit
##########

Running ROS-Groovy
ros-groovy-octomap 1.5.4
ros-groovy-octomap-mapping 0.4.8
ros-groovy octomap-ros 0.2.6

The second image shows that areas previously filled had been removed after some time.
[image: initial octomap]
[image: after 5 minutes]

launch file

```
      <param name="resolution" value="0.2" />        
      <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="/map" />

      <!-- maximum range to integrate (speedup!) -->
      <param name="sensor_model/max_range" type="double" value="30.0" />

      <!-- data source to integrate (PointCloud2) -->
      <remap from="cloud_in" to="/snapshotter/assembled_cloud" />
      <param name="latch" type="bool" value="false" />
      <param name="height_map" type="bool" value="true" />      
      <param name="sensor_model/[hit|miss]" value="0.9 / 0.1" />
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37863/octomap_server-problems/) by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 387 on 2012-07-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-05-13**:
What kind of sensor are you using, and where is is mounted?

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2013-05-13**:
@AHornung I am using a tilting laser similar to the one in PR2. It is mounted on a mast in the front (slightly visible in the first image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As Stefan wrote, octomap_server does not delete nodes on its own. It seems like you are partially clearing cells (setting them to free) with rays that pass through them. Your laser probably has a field of view larger than 180°? The clearing happens when you have the ground filter enabled or misconfigured in octomap_server, or when you are inserting complete 3D scans ray by ray from a shallow angle. This is described in our paper ([http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~hornunga/pub/hornung13auro.pdf](http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Ehornunga/pub/hornung13auro.pdf)) in Fig 10 and 11. If you insert a complete pointcloud in batch from one tilt, this effect should disappear.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. AFAIK, this shouldn't be happening with the plain OctomapServer. Last time I checked, it only added point clouds, but never cleared parts of the tree based on time. Can you edit you post with more details (which version do you use, which kind of sensor data etc.)

For 2) see [answer here](http://answers.ros.org/question/62160/octomap_sever-color-changing/)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-05-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2013-05-12**:
Thank you for your response. I have edited the original question.